# Symfony 4: Make vendor bundle as "own bundle" to develop it easy way?

Tags: symfony4

I want to develop a existing vendor bundle.

So its a lot to do on it and i want to copy this in to my project as my own bundle to develop it easier. Not to overwrite all the stuff.

How can i do this in Symfony 4.3?
Or is there a better way to develop a existing vendor bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general case, you would clone the vendor bundle from the vendor code repository, then make your changes, add features, commit your changes, push them back to the repository, and submit a pull request. If approved, you'll wait for the next version upgrade that includes your changes, after which you can upgrade the code in your vendor folder. The whole edit lifecycle may be slow but that's probably the best way to "develop an existing vendor bundle".

If you want to copy code from a vendor bundle to your own bundle, you'll be developing it as if it's your own code. Check the licences to avoid problems. I'm not sure if this is easier in the long run, though. The original developers will not be reviewing your code so you'd better know what you're doing. You also don't get any upgrades that the vendor developers push to their repository so you might end up manually updating your code.

There might be cases where one approach is better than the other but it'd depend on the case: vendor, bundle, your skills, who the code is for, etc.

This question or answer is not really related to any particular version of Symfony.

Comment: Just to make it clear for me. I have to clone it in to my project? I use it with my project. There i must test it... Sorry never done before. And is there a special place to clone it in and you activate it like normal bundle from vendor?

Comment: No you clone their project as their project on your local environment. If you want to develop a vendor bundle then it's probably not "your project" but the vendor's project. After you've cloned the vendor project, that code will not be in the vendor folder in that project. Treat it as a separate project altogether.